# Calling random functions (C++)

Tags: c++, function, random

I need some help with my C++ program - is it possible to call a random function from a list of functions? I'm new to C++ and only started recently. I've searched pretty much everywhere but I've not got any solutions so far. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the prototypes are the same then you could build up an array of function pointers and pick an element of that array at random. If they are different then you'll need to use something more funky like function objects. Also, see std::function

Comment: you can also find a random number and use it in a switch that all cases call different function

Comment: @adem: much better suggestion!

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow, you should explain what did you tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
srand(time(NULL));
// define your random functions
std::vector<std::function<void()>> functions;
functions.push_back([](){std::cout << "hello"<< std::endl;});
functions.push_back([](){std::cout << "world"<< std::endl;});
functions.push_back([](){std::cout << "merry"<< std::endl;});
functions.push_back([](){std::cout << "christmas"<< std::endl;});
functions.push_back([](){std::cout << "stack"<< std::endl;});
functions.push_back([](){std::cout << "overflow"<< std::endl;});

// call some random functions
for (int i=0; i<functions.size(); ++i)
{
    auto x = rand() % functions.size();
    functions[x]();
}
```

Comment: I'd like to thank uncletall for his help but I don't really understand what the functions.push_back etc does.

Comment: It just adds the function definitions to the end of the vector: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/